# Camera position , just rotate

Tags: unity-game-engine

[ImageCamera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VazjO.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
            transform.Translate(-touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, -touchDeltaPosition.y * speed, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I made a 3D game and I want my camera to stay in the a fix position and just rotate, this is the script that I used. What do I need to add to fix the camera and just rotate?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  you dont want the camera to move at all? or should it stay at a fixed position relative to another object, and rotate around that object?

Comment: The camera will shoot and I want the camera to rotate